# Optimisation of a linear combination

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following simple construction for a set of arbitrary real numbers.

$S=\{s_1,s_2,s_3,...,s_k\}$ where $s_i \in R^+$

$m=\max(S)$

$X=\{x_1,x_2,...x_k;x_i=m/s_i \}$

$y=\sum_{i=1}^{|S|} x_i$

$Z=\{z_1,z_2,z_3,...z_k;z_i=x_i/y\}$

If the values for set Z were provided (and non-trivial eg: not all zeros or ones and any other kind of shenanigans a mathematician might think up), how does one go about working backwards in order to  determine the corresponding values for a set S that meets the above criteria?

What techniques are out there, as nothing I can think of comes to mind.

For example if Z were:

$Z=\{0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4\}$

Comment: Hint: $Z = \left\{\frac{1/s_i}{\sum_j (1/s_j)}: j=1,2,\ldots,k\right\}$.

Comment: What's with the tags? This is not a problem of optimization, linear programming, or Monte Carlo methods.

Comment: @Rn: Because I believe that there isn't a closed-form solution. In similar situations numerical optimisation techniques seem to be the way to go.

Comment: @user1551: I agree, 'm' can be factored out of the summation, but I'm not sure how that helps. could you please provide some more clues.

Comment: Please remove the tags that are based on speculation, and add tags that describe the actual content of the problem, such as [tag:algebra-precalculus].

Comment: @Rn: d o n e.     .

Comment: @Seminar The point is not that we can factor out $m$. It's that if some particular $S$ gives rise to a certain $Z$, then $kS$ will also give rise to the same $Z$ for all $k>0$. So you cannot work out the original $S$ given $Z$, because there are infinitely many legitimate candidates for $S$. If you just want a set $S$ that works, just pick $S=\{1/z_j: j=1,\ldots,k\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't be done. If $S=\{{2,3\}}$, then $m=3$, $X=\{{2/3,1\}}$, $y=5/3$, $Z=\{{2/5,3/5\}}$, but you'll get the same $Z$ if you start with $S=\{{200000000,300000000\}}$. Thus, given $Z$, you can't tell what $S$ was.

Comment: I believe I misworded the question, I understand there could be many solutions for S given a particular Z - So I guess the question should be any particular S - I apologize formal mathematical definitions is not my strong suite.

Comment: If you're happy with any $S$ that leads to a given $Z$, you can just take $S=Z$.

Comment: Fair enough. though not what I was hoping in terms of an answer.

Comment: I think you need $S=\{1/z_i\}$. The question has $x_i=m/s_i$ not $s_i/m$.

Comment: @WeirdSymbol, oops!

Comment: @Rn: If we were to assume that, then for the given example at the bottom of the question, $z_1$ would be recalculated as being 0.48

Comment: @Seminar: No, it wouldn't. $S=(10,5,3\frac13,2.5)$, $m=10$, $X=(1,2,3,4)$, $y=10$, $Z=(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4)$. Maybe you made a typo, and you really did mean $x_i=s_i/m$ instead of what you wrote.